# Why is div inside of the other div?

Tags: html, css, django

I have the following django template code. The main-card-faq div is clearly not in the main-card div however it keeps getting rendered inside of the main-card div. Any idea what could be going on?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="main-card">

{% if heading_info %}
  {% for heading in heading_info %}

{% include  'partials/_heading.html' %}

  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

{% if welcome_info  %}
{% for welcome in  welcome_info%}

{% include  'partials/_welcome.html' %}

{% endfor %}

{% endif %}

{% comment %} {% if skills_info %}
{% for  skill in  skills_info%}

{% include  'partials/_skills.html' %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %} {% endcomment %}

  </div>
  
  <div class="main-card-faq">
  {% include  'partials/_faq.html' %}

  </div>

  test



{% endblock %}
```

Comment: good idea @hackape. Just found out the issue is in the welcome tag. still going through it

Comment: Glad it helps. Care to boost my scores?

Comment: done! There was a missing div closing tag in the welcome partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mismatching closing tag I guess. It's hard to tell since you've included a lot of `{% ... %}` in between. You just need to be patient and debug carefully.

Try remove all those `{%...%}` directives, and leave only "main-card" and "main-card-faq" divs, see if problem goes away. Then re-insert those directives, one by one, re-render to check the result, until a point it breaks, then you know the last inserted directive cause the problem.